# How do I close the files in this function using with?

Tags: python, optimization, file-io

I have the following function. The program looks at each file and prints the lines occuring in all 4 files to a new file. I've tried `file1.close()` but I get an error about closing a set? I think I could use a `with` statement but not sure how to do this, I'm very new to programming.

```
def secretome():
    file1 = set(line.strip() for line in open(path + "goodlistSigP.txt"))
    file2 = set(line.strip() for line in open(path + "tmhmmGoodlist.txt"))
    file3 = set(line.strip() for line in open(path + "targetpGoodlist.txt"))
    file4 = set(line.strip() for line in open(path + "wolfPsortGoodlist.txt"))
    newfile = open(path + "secretome_pass.txt", "w")
    for line in file1 & file2 & file3 & file4:
        if line:
            newfile.write(line + '\n')
    newfile.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest removing the repetition by extracting your set generation into a function:

```
def set_from_file(path):
    with open(path) as file:
        return set(lines.strip() for line in file)

def secretome():
    files = ["goodlistSigP.txt", "tmhmmGoodlist.txt", "targetpGoodlist.txt", "wolfPsortGoodlist.txt"]
    data = [set_from_file(os.path.join(path, file)) for file in files]
    with open(path + "secretome_pass.text", "w") as newfile:
        newfile.writelines(line + "/n" for line in set.union(*data) if line)
```

Note that you are doing intersection in your code, but you talk about wanting a union, so I used `union()` here. There are also a couple of [list comprehensions/generator expressions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

Comment: I think your newfile doesn't have newlines.  Otherwise, good answer.  beat me by a minute or so.

Comment: As a side note, maybe `newfile.writelines(line+'\n' for line in ... if line)` might be a little cleaner

Comment: @mgilson Good suggestions, I'll make the changes.

Comment: This becomes a fun one with `itertools`.  See my (new, non-duplicate) answer if you're interested :)

Comment: One final comment:  `set().union(*data)` is more simply written (in this case) as `set.union(*data)` since the first object you pass in is already an instance of `set`.

Comment: @mgilson Good call, changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could put it into a generator:

```
def closingfilelines(*a):
    with open(*a) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield f
```

and use it where you currently use `open()`.

While the generator runs, the file is kept open, and if the generator is exhausted, it gets closed.

The same happens if the generator object is `.close()`d or dropped - in this case, the generator gets a `GeneratorExit` exception, which makes the `with` clause be left as well.

Comment: I don't think that `open(*a)` is what you want here ... is it?

Comment: @mgilson Why not? So I can do `set(line.strip() for line in closingfilelines(path + "goodlistSigP.txt"))` as the OP wanted, as well as `closingfilelines(path + "goodlistSigP.txt", "r+b", 1024)` if needed.

Comment: Admittedly, my solution is not so good as the ones which include the `set()` building into their function as well, but it is not SO bad, is it?

Comment: I see, I wasn't sure if you wanted to do the loop over the files implicitly, or if you wanted to be able to pass a "mode" (hence my "is it?" question).

Comment: This makes it a (nearly) perfect replacement for `open()`. (Nearly because I don't deal with keyword arguments...)

Comment: There is no reason to make a generator, it makes far more sense just to return the file object which can be iterated over, and then used for anything else too.

Comment: @Lattyware -- This is one sublety that I've never been sure of.  If you return the file object, it will be closed by the context manager (won't it?)

Comment: @glglgl -- In any event, I'm not the downvoter here, so I can't undo it.  I just wanted clarification on what you were proposing.

Comment: @mgilson Right, exactly. That's why either a generator is necessary or a completet processing of the file. Others chose the latter, I chose the former.

Comment: After thinking about it, I'm happy enough with this solution.  It addresses OP's original question "How do I get a context manager around these open statements".  +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

To take this a completely different direction than my original (which Lattyware beat me to):

You could define a function:

```
def file_lines(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
         for line in f:
             yield line
```

Now you can use `itertools.chain` to iterate over your files:

```
import itertools
def set_from_file(path):
    filenames = ("name1","name2","name3",...)  #your input files go here
    lines = itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.imap(file_lines,filenames))
    #lines is an iterable object.  
    #At this point, virtually none of your system's resources have been consumed
    with open("output",'w') as fout:
         #Now we only need enough memory to store the non-duplicate lines :)
         fout.writelines(set( line.strip()+'\n' for line in lines) )
```

Comment: +1, a good solution, although do note it won't remove duplicates like the original.

Comment: @Lattyware -- Why won't duplicates be removed?  At the end of the day, each line of each of the files is passed to a set which gets passed to `writelines`.

Comment: @Lattyware -- Phew.  you had me worried for a minute there since you're nearly always right about these things :)

Comment: XD, I'm definitely getting worse at reading code too quickly and making assumptions, I think there is a new year's resolution in there somewhere to check my thoughts before I post.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a very complicated way of doing it. I'd suggest something like the example I've given here.

```
import fileinput
files = ['file1.txt','file2.txt','file3.txt','file4.txt']  
output = open('output.txt','w')

for file in files:
    for line in fileinput.input([file]):
        output.write(line)
    output.write('\n')

output.close()
```

This code creates a list with the files in it (replace the names with the required filepaths), creates a file to store the output of each and then simply iterates through them using the fileinput module to go through each one line by line, printing each line to the output file as it goes. The 'output.write('\n')' ensures that the printing of the next file's lines starts on a new line in the output file.

Comment: Why not just do `for line in fileinput.input(list):`?, but the idea here is rock solid (I like it a lot).  It's basically what I reproduced in my answer using `itertools` (forgot about `fileinput`).  The only down-side is that it doesn't really help OP learn about context managers.  Also, Please don't use `list` as a variable name, and please use `open` to open a file.

Comment: A good solution, although do note it won't remove duplicates like the original, also note that `file()` to open a file is a bad idea as mgilson said. Plus, you should really use the `with` statement.

Comment: Yeah you're right about list as a variable name alright, mea culpa. As far as using 'for line in fileinput.input(list)', that won't allow for the addition of newlines at the end of the last line of each file, which could mean that the first line of a new file will be printed on the same line as the last line of the previous one.